# Debian 10 disk clone to lower sized disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, debian, clone

I am trying to clone my Debian 10 disk image that is currently installed on a 1TB HDD. I have resized the Linux filesystem Partition to 16GB and the rest is unallocated. The allocated space is at the end address. So in total I have 3 partitions - boot/efi(512MB), filesystem(16GB), Linux Swap(8GB). I used Gparted to recreate partitions (copy paste) to my 64 GB USB drive. Then I used Clonezilla partition to partition transfer to transfer the data with -r -icds enabled . However the system won't boot. 
Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate UUIDs whether BIOS or UEFI. And if UEFI with gpt cannot have duplicate GUIDs. Because gpt has GUID in primary partition table, backup partition table & partition, typically you cannot copy partitions as GUIDs then do not match. Often easier just to reinstall, and restore you data from your backup (you do have data backup?). I export list of apps, /home & my data. Some settings in /etc as my backup of Ubuntu. Often then better to have /home as separate partition.

Comment: Oh. So there is no way to do that besides getting a hard drive of the same size or greater? I basically wanted to clone my whole system and make it bootable on a lower sized disk.

Comment: If UEFI with gpt, I do believe you can use dd but only from same size or larger. Data may be written anywhere on drive. And if drive is larger, you then have to move backup gpt partition table to end of drive. I have seen users use clonezilla or other image tools, not copy partition tools.  But I still suggest a new install & restore data, apps & maybe system setting from your backup.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to copy some data that lives *outside* of a partition:

- If you use BIOS boot mode, the bootloader starts at sector 0 i.e. the MBR, and (in case of GRUB) extends to sectors 1–32ish. Easiest is to just reinstall the bootloader using its own tools.
- If you use UEFI boot mode, the firmware stores boot entries which reference the EFI system partition GUID – not the one that's stored in the filesystem, but the one that's stored in the GPT partition table itself. Linux tools call it the "PARTUUID".

So if you cloned the EFI system partition to an internal disk, there are several options which may fix it:

1. You can use the <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> command in `fdisk`, or the <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> command in `gdisk`, to change the EFI partition's GUID to match the original one.
2. You can use `efibootmgr` to create a new firmware boot entry that refers to the new GUID.
3. You can try copying the `grubx64.efi` file to `<EFI>/EFI/Boot/BootX64.efi`, which is the default location when all firmware boot entries fail.

If you cloned to a removable drive, I think you **must** do option 3.

Comment: as you preferred Option 3 I browsed my EFI file folder. I find grubx64.efi in EFI/debian/